# Four Colour Theorem - What was wrong with De Morgan's 'proof'

Tags: graph-theory

Every resource I can find mentions his 'proof' but then just goes on to other ideas.

Is it because he could not prove his theory?

Surely it is trivial to prove using graph theory notation. (Or don't I know enough about graph theory to see why it isn't?)

Comment: [This](https://nrich.maths.org/6291#:~:text=De%20Morgan%20used%20the%20fact,the%20basis%20of%20his%20proof.) might help you.

Comment: That was one of the resources I tried. It does exactly what a said above: mentions his 'proof' and then skips onto other ideas.

Comment: Wait a second. What proof is trivial?

Answer (score 2):

In chapter 2, [pg. 17](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s10116.pdf) of *Four Colors Suffice: How the Map Problem was Solved*
by Robin J. Wilson:

> In this passage De Morgan hits upon the fact that if a map contains
> four regions, each adjoining the other three, then one of them must be
> completely enclosed by the others. He believed, incorrectly, that this
> idea lay at the heart of the problem, and it soon became an obsession of
> his. Since he could not prove it, he proposed to assume its truth as an
> axiom, which he defined as “a proposition which cannot be made dependent upon obviously more simple ones.”

Specifically in De Morgan's letter to William Whewell, Master of Trinity College in  Cambridge in December 1853, he wrote:

> I soon made out the following—which was at first incredible—then certainly
> true—then axiomatic—for I cannot make it depend on anything I see more
> clearly.
>
> [image]
>
> If four non-interfering compartments have each common boundary line
> with the other three—one at least of the four must be inclosed by the other
> three—or by fewer . . .

**EDIT:** @WizardMath, see below:

On [pg. 167](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00327701) of *De Morgan on Map Colouring and the Separation Axiom* by N. L. Bigg in the Archive for History of Exact Sciences volume 28, pages165–170 (1983), the axiom in modern terms could be summarised as follows:

> **Axiom.** If four regions are mutually adjacent, then one is inclosed.
>
> **Theorem.** Any plane map requires at most four colours.
>
> **Proof.** (By induction.) The result is true for any map with not more than four regions. Suppose is it true for maps with at most $n$ regions, and let $M$ be a map with $n+1$ regions.
>
> (i) If $M$ has four mutually adjacent regions, one of them is surrounded by the others. Removing (of shriking) this region results in a map $M'$ with $n$ regions, which can be four-coloured by the induction hypothesis. When the lost region is reinstated it is adjacent to at most three colours, and so there is a colour available for it.
>
> (ii) If $M$ does not have four mutually adjacent regions, four colours are never needed in a 'neighbourhood' and so the induction step proceeds as in (i). Thus the theorem holds for each $n$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a link where we can find proof of this theorem which doesnt required computer programming ?

Comment: This summarizes De Morgans attempt at a proof, but I don't see anywhere where it says which part is actually wrong/ incomplete in it. Is the axiom false? or does it require a proof that is essentially equivalent to the 4 color theorem? or is the issue in (ii) of the proof which looks dubious to me?

Comment: If the statement above: " He believed, incorrectly, that this idea lay at the heart of the problem" is correct, it moves me forward a step, but R Wilson does not go on to explain why the idea does not (or could not) be at the centre of a solution to the problem.

Comment: The axiom is true; step (ii) of the proof is nonsense. Moreover, if we never rely on having a planar graph except in using the axiom, we are in trouble, because there are non-planar graphs without four mutually adjacent regions that require arbitrarily many colors to color.

Comment: Think of a graph that is a circle with an odd but very large number of vertices. "Locally" you don't need more than 2 colors to color it, you always alternate. And if the number of vertices is large, this "local" property carries a long way. But ultimately, you get around the whole circle and find that at the end you need a third color to color that circle because otherwise the first vertex you started coloring and the last when you have "run around the circle" have the same color, and they are neighbors in the circle. That shows that an argument of kind (ii) is way to simplistic.